# Show a Specific page on Liiferay start up

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 .
I have deployed a Liferay Struts Portlet inside Tomcat Server .
I have used Service Builder and modified LocalServiceUtil classes and ServiceImple classes to insert data into Database . Its working fine .

My question is , i have a JSP Page in this portlet called as Login.jsp , please tell me how can i make this as landing page ??

I have modified the portal-ext.properties and portal.properties also , but still it is not working .

In case we cannot make a Portlet Page as a Landing Page , please tell me how can we display a Custom page ??

Thank you very much in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can setup this page to be your Home URL and Default Landing Page. Navigate to Control Panel->Portal->Settings section and update fields like - Home URL - Default Landing Page - Log out page.

Where - 
Home URL - This is the home page of the portal. For example, if you want the home page to be http:// servernamae:8080/web/guest/home, then set this to /web/guest/home.

Default Landing Page - This is the home page of the portal. For example, if you want the home page to be http:// servernamae:8080/web/guest/home, then set this to /web/guest/home.
Default Landing Page

Does that help?